# Wysiwyg editor to drag and drop components to website

Tags: php, drag-and-drop, web

I am trying to build website builder where I can select my templates and add/delete drag and drop components I need. Any suggestions on which WYSIWYG editor suits this need ? ??

Comment: Well it depends. I built myself a drag and drop editor using bootstrap 3 framework. Then I use TinyMCE as an editor. Both TinyMCE and CKEditor have inline editing options. Both also have the ability to add full HTML pages to edit. Something I also use for another project. Then I use Elfinder for uploading and file management. Which also has resize, crop and rotate for images. I drag and drop various columns and image columns. Then make those editable inside each column. You will have to do some modification to both editors. to prevent them from removing specific tags. TinyMCE being #1 to use.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for something along the same lines. I found this http://imperavi.com/kube I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for but thought I would try and help out in any way i can.